# ASP.NET File Upload Control Databinding

Tags: asp.net

Am using FileUpload control to upload files from client.
When i click on calendar date, it went off am not able to see the file name in file upload control.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, Can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Label` or other control to show a file name. You can't bind a value to the `Fileupload` control properties.